# How to extract substring between two substrings from a string in php?

Tags: php, string

For example:

```
 $string="<aa>xyz<bb>123<ccc>";
```

I want to get the substring 'xyz' from $string.Is it possible?

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: ok, since you have the substrings that are to the left and right of the substring you want, do ltrim and rtrim of left and right substrings on main string to get what you want. <insert evil smile>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a regex to explode the string into an array. this would give you the substring you want in $arr[0]
This will work regardless what the tags are, and allow you to easily which ever substring you want.

```
<?php
$string="<aa>xyz<bb>123<ccc>";
$arr = preg_split("/<[^>]+>/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_export($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can use strip_tags to get `xyz`

```
<?php
      echo strip_tags('<aa>xyz<bb>');
    ?>
```

`strip_tags` is only striping tags. Use it only if this meets your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible

```
 $string="<aa>xyz<bb>";

 echo substr($string,4,4);
```

you can also do this by [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)  it Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match` with `<aa>(.*?)</bb>` , it will be the first match.

With regular expressions you will also be able to get other matches in your string also ..